# inline source map with closure compiler?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, source-maps

I'm struggling to debug a js file compiled by Closure Compiler with its corresponding source map file (issue: associated file source code not displayed in Chrome/firefox).

Is there a way with Closure Compiler to put the source map 'inline', in the compiled js file (instead of generating a separated source map file) ?

If not, is it possible to modify the compiled js file to replace the source map link by the source map content?